# How to emulate #include <myFile.txt> with Linux commands

Tags: text-processing

So, I am trying to create an output file from a source file that includes other files.

(My use-case is actually YAML for Kubernetes/OpenShift but these .txt files show the aim.)

For example:

```
% cat source.txt
This is the source files it will include two other files.
The first will be here:
#INCLUDE ./first-included-file.txt
And the second file will be inserted here:
#INCLUDE ./second-included-file.txt
And this is the end of source.txt
```

And if the included files are:

```
% cat first-included-file.txt
This is FIRST
End of FIRST

% cat second-included-file.txt
This is SECOND
End of SECOND
```

Then the output will be:

```
This is the source files it will include two other files.
The first will be here:
This is FIRST
End of FIRST
And the second file will be inserted here:
This is SECOND
End of SECOND
And this is the end of source.txt
```

Other answers use

```
sed '/#INCLUDE/ r insertfile'
```

but is there a generic solution that can find the filename from the value in the source?

I guess a Bash script that read and parsed each line might do the job but, perhaps, `awk` or something else could do this?

Comment: While you could write something in bash, IMO it's a better route to use an existing templating system. For k8s manifest templating specifically, [jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/) and [helm](https://helm.sh/) are popular choices. Also while it is not templating, [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) is officially supported by k8s and aims to eliminate the need to template manifests.

Answer (score 8):

**[cpp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)** - The C preprocessor command can be used. This command is usually included in the `gcc` or `cpp` packages in most Linux distributions.

Although it's called a C preprocessor, it can be used on other files as well, and you can use standard C preprocessor directives such as `#include`, `#define`, `#ifdef` and so on.

For example:

**source.txt**

```c
This is the source files it will include two other files.
The first will be here:
#include "first-included-file.txt"
And the second file will be inserted here:
#include "second-included-file.txt"
And this is the end of source.txt
```

**first-included-file.txt**

```
This is FIRST
End of FIRST
```

**second-included-file.txt**

```
This is SECOND
End of SECOND
```

**output of `cpp -P source.txt`**

```
$ cpp -P source.txt
This is the source files it will include two other files.
The first will be here:
This is FIRST
End of FIRST
And the second file will be inserted here:
This is SECOND
End of SECOND
And this is the end of source.txt
```

---

notes:

- The `-P` flag inhibits generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor.
- [manual page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/cpp.1.en)
- Regarding "you can use standard C preprocessor directives such as
  #include, #define, #ifdef and so on." - but if you don't want that and instead just want files included as-is then in addition to
  converting each #INCLUDE to #include and wrapping your included file
  names in quotes, you must do something to disable any occurrences of
  the strings #include, #define, #ifdef, etc. that might just happen to
  be in your input before running cpp otherwise it'll undesirably
  transform your text based on those strings appearing.
- You may also get unexpected results if the file to be included is missing from the local directory (assuming your implementation of cpp does search the local directory first, as is usually the case) but cpp can find a file of the same name in one of the other implementation-defined directories it searches for include files.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the information. Would you mind editing this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking "d) Recursive-descent parsing of an input file or files, e.g.:" in http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to match on `#INCLUDE` instead of  `include` and work even if your file names include non-newline white spaces you could do the following with any awk:

```
awk '
    function read(file) {
        while ( (getline < file) > 0) {
            if ( sub(/^#INCLUDE[ \t]+/,"") ) {
                read($0)
            } else {
                print
            }
        }
        close(file)
     }
     BEGIN {
         read(ARGV[1])
     }
' source.txt
This is the source files it will include two other files.
The first will be here:
This is FIRST
End of FIRST
And the second file will be inserted here:
This is SECOND
End of SECOND
And this is the end of source.txt
```

The above assumes you don't have recursive includes - if you do then add whatever logic is necessary to implement whatever you want that recursion to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Both Perl and Raku have a quoting construct known as `heredocs` (i.e. quote "doc `:to` here"), which can provide the desired output:*

**source.txt**

```perl
my $file1 = '/path/to/first-included-file.txt'.IO.lines.join("\n");
my $file2 = '/path/to/second-included-file.txt'.IO.lines.join("\n");

my $pre-processed = qs:to/TERMINATOR/;
This is the source files it will include two other files.
The first will be here:
$file1
And the second file will be inserted here:
$file2
And this is the end of source.txt
TERMINATOR

put $pre-processed;
```

**first-included-file.txt**

```
This is FIRST
End of FIRST
```

**second-included-file.txt**

```
This is SECOND
End of SECOND
```

**output of `raku source.txt`**

```
This is the source files it will include two other files.
The first will be here:
This is FIRST
End of FIRST
And the second file will be inserted here:
This is SECOND
End of SECOND
And this is the end of source.txt
```

You don't need to learn the entirety of the Raku language to only use this quoting language, known as "Q-lang" (or slang) in Raku lingo. Above, the minimal interpolation is invoked using the `qs:to/TERMINATOR/;` code. Here, `qs` tells Raku to only interpolate "scalar" or `$`-sigiled variables (using `qq` instead will interpolate all Raku variables). Other (intermediate) interpolation options can be found below.

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/heredocs%20%3Ato
https://docs.raku.org/language/quoting
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76624379/7270649
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed`:

```bash
sed 's/^#INCLUDE /cat /e' source.txt
```

The `e` flag will execute the contents of the pattern space as a shell command and replace it with the output.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that that'll only work at 1 level so if source.txt contains `#INCLUDE foo` and foo contains `#INCLUDE bar`, bar won't be expanded in the output, it'll still show `#INCLUDE bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The "m4" macro (name starts with 'm' and has 4 following letters) program will do includes. HOWEVER, the form of the include is: "include (`file')". See "info m4".