# Is there a way to replace bash source commands with the code from the source file?

Tags: bash, shell

For example, you might write a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: foo/bar.sh

echo_foo(){
  echo "foo"
}
```

With a main file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: foo.sh
. foo/bar.sh

echo_foo
```

Which, when executed, outputs:

```
$ ./foo.sh
foo
```

---

But what I want is to have that compact `foo.sh` file with imports, and now create a `flat-foo.sh` from that `foo.sh` file:

```
flatten foo.sh > foobar.sh
```

So that `foobar.sh` has all the content of the source commands injected in place, and is a stand-alone unit:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# file: boobar.sh

echo_foo(){
  echo "foo"
}

echo_foo
```

---

This seems like a problem that has been solved before, and before I implement it or dive further, is there a straightforward way to achieve this with bash files?

Comment: In the general case, this impossible without executing the code, because unlike C `#include`s, the file that is being sourced (a) need not be statically defined, and (b) may not even be a regular file

Comment: @muru and if it cannot be implemented generally, there is no point in supporting some subset of the functionality -- too much ambiguity, got it.  So I'll do it myself for my use case.  Thank you for confirming at least to some extent this kind of tool has not been implemented already -- frees me up.

Comment: For the simpler cases, you can try adapting https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/750819/70524

Answer (score 1):

For the simple cases, it's not too hard with Perl:

```
% perl -pe '$_ = qx/cat $1/ if /^\. (.*)$/;' main.sh
#!/bin/bash
# file: foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
# file: foo/bar.sh

echo_foo(){
  echo "foo"
}

echo_foo
```

You'll have to relax the pattern a bit if you need to support e.g. indented `.` commands, and of course this will fail if you have something like `. /dev/stdin < ...` or `. <(whatever)`, or `. "./dir/$scriptname"`, let alone something where the command continues past a newline... But as long as you don't have any such. One possibility would also be to only replace `.` commands on lines that have some special comment marker, e.g. `. somefile.sh # flatten`

(Funnily enough, it does support filenames with whitespace, at least provided the shell that `qx//` starts is the same as the one that the main script uses.)

Comment: +1. To cope with leading whitespace and `source` as well as `.` and any amount of whitespace before the filename-to-source: `if /^\h*(?:\.|source)\h+(.*)/`.  It still won't work with stdin or process substitution filename variables or multi-line continuation etc.   BTW, it's worth reading `perldoc -f qx` to get an understanding of the quirks and caveats and risks of executing arbitrary strings. and `perldoc perlsec` too.